# Bootstrap3 model overlap by the Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used a slider and a Bootstrap v3 model to my site. Model working fine but it is overlap by the slider. This is my site: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/project2/index.html. In footer section, there is a  contact link. Please click on it and see the result. How can I solved this? I fall in the same problem for YouTube video and I use `?wmode=transparent` at the end of the video link. I don't find any solution for slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change z-index property of following class:

```
.da-dots {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
left: 0px;
bottom: 20px;
z-index: 2000;  <<-- Here change to less than 1050.
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Your `z-index` property for `.da-dots` less than your modal dialogs `z-index` property which is equal to 1050.

Answer (score 0):

.contact-form-wrapper needs

> z-index: 1;

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of those .da-dots is 2000

Set it to something under 1000 and you should be fine.